# Do I got this change of basis problem right?

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

[image]

[image]

I posted parts of this problem earlier, but I have now managed to solve it. Since I don't get any respons in my earlier post if my solution is right or not, I post it again here. My friends and I don't have the same answer for this task, more spesificly problem (ii) and (iii). I wondered if someone could check if I got it right?

So I have solved (i) and think I got it right:

$$P_{\beta\rightarrow\epsilon}=\pmatrix{cos\theta & -sin\theta\\sin\theta&cos\theta}$$

$$P_{\epsilon\rightarrow\beta}=\pmatrix{cos\theta & sin\theta\\-sin\theta&cos\theta}$$

For (ii) I have done this:

$\pmatrix{x'\\y'}=P_{\epsilon\rightarrow\beta}\pmatrix{x\\y}=\pmatrix{cos\theta & sin\theta\\-sin\theta&cos\theta}\pmatrix{x\\y}$ that gives us that

$x'=xcos\theta+ysin\theta$

$y'=-xsin\theta+ycos\theta$

For (iii) I have done this:

$\pmatrix{x\\y}=P_{\beta\rightarrow\epsilon}\pmatrix{x'\\y'}=\pmatrix{cos\theta & -sin\theta\\sin\theta&cos\theta}\pmatrix{x'\\y'}$

So we must have that:

$x=x'cos\theta-y'sin\theta$

$y=x'sin\theta+y'cos\theta$

And we use in these expressions for y and x in the equation $xy=1$ and get that:

$(x'cos\theta-y'sin\theta)(x'sin\theta+y'cos\theta)=1$ Rembering that $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$ the equation is equal to

$(x'\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-y'\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})(x'\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+y'\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})=1$

The hyperbola is then given by the equation:

$\frac{1}{2}(x')^2-\frac{1}{2}(y')^2=1$

Comment: You can type `\cos`, `\sin`, etc. to get nicer-looking trig expressions. You can use `\mathcal` to get "curly" letters like in the problem image: `$\mathcal{B}, \mathcal{E}, \mathcal{P}$` is $\mathcal{B}, \mathcal{E}, \mathcal{P}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your methods and answers look correct.

We can check these answers:

For part (ii), saying that $\vec u = \left(\begin{array}{c} x' \\ y' \end{array}\right)$ in $\mathcal{B}$-coordinates means

$$ \vec u = x' \vec u_1 + y' \vec u_2 $$

So in $\mathcal{E}$-coordinates,

$$ \vec u = (x \cos \theta + y \sin \theta)
 \left(\begin{array}{c} \cos \theta \\ \sin \theta \end{array}\right)
 + (-x \sin \theta + y \cos \theta)
 \left(\begin{array}{c} -\sin \theta \\ \cos \theta \end{array}\right) \\
\vec u = \left(\begin{array}{c}
x \cos^2 \theta + y \sin \theta \cos \theta + x \sin^2 \theta - y \sin \theta \cos \theta \\
x \sin \theta \cos \theta + y \sin^2 \theta - x \sin \theta \cos \theta + y \cos^2 \theta
 \end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{c} x \\ y \end{array}\right) $$

Good, it's still the same vector.

For part (iii), we could transform the whole equation back to $x$-$y$ coordinates, but instead let's take a sample point and see if it works. $(2, \frac{1}{2})$ in $\mathcal{E}$-coordinates is on the curve. In $\mathcal{B}$-coordinates, we have

$$ \left(\begin{array}{c} x' \\ y' \end{array}\right) =
P_{\mathcal{E} \to \mathcal{B}} \left(\begin{array}{c} x \\ y \end{array}\right)
= \left(\begin{array}{cc} \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \\
\frac{-\sqrt{2}}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \end{array}\right)
\! \left(\begin{array}{c} 2 \\ \frac{1}{2} \end{array}\right)
= \sqrt{2} \left(\begin{array}{c} 1 + \frac{1}{4} \\
 -1 + \frac{1}{4} \end{array} \right)
= \frac{\sqrt{2}}{4} \left(\begin{array}{c} 5 \\ -3 \end{array}\right) $$

Plugging into the left side of your hyperbola equation,

$$ \frac 12 (x')^2 - \frac 12 (y')^2
 = \frac 12 \left(\frac{5 \sqrt 2}{4}\right)^2 -
      \frac 12 \left(\frac{-3 \sqrt 2}{4}\right)^2
 = \frac{5^2 - 3^2}{4^2} = 1 $$

Checks out!

Comment: Thank you so much for the confirmation! Really appreciate your help! :)